# How to properly use useField hook from Formik in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I followed everything from [documentation](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/useField)
and watched the tutorial by [Ben Awad on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FD50LPJ6bjE&t=1132s). And still, I cannot get it to work.

```
const TextField = (props: FieldHookConfig<{}>) => {
    const [field] = useField(props);
        return (
            <div>
                <input {...field} {...props}/>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

I used the `FieldHookConfig` as the type for the props because the `useField` is expecting a `string` or the `FieldHookConfig` base on the Field.d.ts file. yet typescript is still not happy.

it complains right in this line `<input {...field} {...props}/>`

```
(property) JSX.IntrinsicElements.input: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>
Type '{ ref?: string | ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLInputElement> | null | undefined; key?: string | number | undefined; ... 289 more ...; innerRef?: ((instance: any) => void) | undefined; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.
  Type '{ ref?: string | ((instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLSelectElement> | null | undefined; key?: string | number | undefined; ... 269 more ...; checked?: boolean | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.
    Type '{ ref?: string | ((instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLSelectElement> | null | undefined; key?: string | number | undefined; ... 269 more ...; checked?: boolean | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ClassAttributes<HTMLInputElement>'.
      Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | ((instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLSelectElement> | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLInputElement> | null | undefined'.
          Type '(instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLInputElement> | null | undefined'.
            Type '(instance: HTMLSelectElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void'.
              Types of parameters 'instance' and 'instance' are incompatible.
                Type 'HTMLInputElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLSelectElement | null'.
                  Type 'HTMLInputElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLSelectElement': length, options, selectedIndex, selectedOptions, and 4 more.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are 2 problems, firstly, you cannot spread the `props` variable on the `<input>` element, due to the incompatible types (as specified in the error). Secondly, your generic type for `FieldHookConfig` shouldn't be `{}`, rather it should be `string`

So to fix it, suppose you are using your `<TextField>` element like so

```js
<TextField
  name="firstName"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Jane"
/>
```

Then inside your `TextField` definition, you will write

```js
const TextField = (props: FieldHookConfig<string>) => {
  const [field] = useField(props);
  return (
    <div>
      {/* no need to pass the name field because Formik will accept
      that prop internally and pass it to the field variable */}
      <input {...field} placeholder={props.placeholder} type={props.type} />
    </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: So I have to declare each extra property on the input field directly, there is no way to spread them?

Answer (score 12):

Just to add to the above, the `useField()` documentation referenced above shows `label` being included in the `MyTextField` properties.  In order to make this type of call:

```
<TextField name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="Jane" label="First Name" />
```

add the following interface:

```
interface OtherProps {
  label : string
}
```

Then change the first line of the function expression above to:

```
const TextField = (props : OtherProps & FieldHookConfig<string>) => {
```

You can then reference the passed `label` by calling `props.label` within the function's return block like this, for example:

```
<label htmlFor={props.id || props.name}>{props.label}</label>
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to declare each argument separately and can't just pass `{...props}` to the element?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone still experiencing the same issue try the following:

```
import { ClassAttributes, InputHTMLAttributes } from "react"
import { useField, FieldHookConfig } from "formik"

const TextField = (props: InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & ClassAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & FieldHookConfig<string>) => {
    const [field] = useField(props);
        return (
            <div>
                <input {...field} {...props}/>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

And if you have a destructured props you could do this:

```
type TextFieldProps = {
  label: string;
};

const TextField = ({label, ...props}: TextFieldProps & InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> &
ClassAttributes<HTMLInputElement> &
FieldHookConfig<string>) => {
    const [field] = useField(props);
        return (
            <div>
                <input {...field} {...props}/>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

Comment: @khierl with this you can simply spread the props, please consider marking this as the accepted answer! I just had to omit ref from the resulting props type.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved this issue, using formik [docs](https://formik.org/docs/api/useField#fieldhookconfigvalue)

Actually Typescript was satisfied just after I added 'name: string;' to my InputProps.

```js
type InputProps = {
  label: string;
  name: string;
  validate?: (value: any) => undefined | string | Promise<any>;
  type?: string;
  multiple?: boolean;
  value?: string;
};

export const TextInput = ({ label, ...props }: InputProps) => {
  const [field, meta]  = useField(props);
  return (
    <div className=" my-3">
      {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
        <>
          <input className="form-control" {...field} {...props} />
          <div className="error error-check text-danger">{meta.error}</div>
        </>
      ) : (
        <input className="form-control" {...field} {...props} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```